# clicking button to go to another screen - crashes

Tags: android, android-activity

on my main activity screen, I have a button which takes me to another screen. but when I click that my app crashes and I get an error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.app.appname/com.app.appname.view}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

The blue underline is at view.java at this line:

> ArrayList spinnerArrayList =
>   bundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");

Here is my full view.java code:

```
public class view extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
    private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TextView> mTextviews = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EditText> mEdittexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<View> mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView textview;
    private CheckBox checkbox;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        GlobalClass globalClass = (GlobalClass) this.getApplicationContext();
        textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(String.valueOf(mSpinners)); // add you selected item
        globalClass.setItems(items);
        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();
        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);
        findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout).requestFocus();







        Intent gotIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extraBundle");

        ArrayList<Integer> spinnerArrayList = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");


        //creating a for loop, to create the number of spinners in the spinnerarray list size
        for(int i = 0; i < spinnerArrayList.size(); i++) {
            final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
            mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);

            final View newView = makeView();
            //Add a new view
            mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
            mViews.add(newView);


            final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
            mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
            mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);


            final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
            mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

            //TODO add checkbox to your list
            mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);


            final TextView newTextview = makeTextview();
            mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
            mTextviews.add(newTextview);




            newCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.

                    newCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    newView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    newEdittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    newTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    newCheckbox.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            newCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });



                    spinner.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                    newView.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            newView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                    newEdittext.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            newEdittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                    newTextview.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            newTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });




                }
            });








            //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                    String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                    //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                    //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                    newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    //  code here
                }
            });


            final int listSize = mViews.size();

            //code for deleting the said item.
            newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                //start
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                    final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.this);


                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity


                                    if (listSize > 0) {

                                        mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }


                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();


                }
            });






            //setting spinner selection values
            int positionOfSpinner = spinnerArrayList.get(i);
            spinner.setSelection(positionOfSpinner);




        }









            //code for the add button to add more items
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);



        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                // Handle ze click.
                final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);



                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins(5, 100, 10, 0); //top 70

                Resources resources = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

                layoutParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
                layoutParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                final View newView = makeView();
                //Add a new view
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


                final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);


                final int listSize = mViews.size();


                //code for deleting the said item.
                //code for deleting the said item.
                newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.this);


                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity
                                        //final int listSize = mViews.size();


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }


                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });


                //Add a new checkbox
                final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);



                newCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.

                        newCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        newView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        newEdittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        newCheckbox.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                newCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });



                        spinner.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });

                        newView.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                newView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });

                        newEdittext.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                newEdittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });


                      /*  textview.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });*/


                    }
                });






                final TextView newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);

                //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                        String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                        //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                        //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                        newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        //  code here
                    }

                });


            }
        });

    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent startSettingsActivity = new Intent(this, settings.class);
            startActivity(startSettingsActivity);
            //start the settings activity here.
            return true;
        }


       /* else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {

            for(int j=0; j<mCheckboxes.size(); j++){
                mCheckboxes.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            for(int j=0; j<mSpinners.size(); j++){
                mSpinners.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            for(int j=0; j<mViews.size(); j++){
                mViews.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            for(int j=0; j<mTextviews.size(); j++){
                mTextviews.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            for(int j=0; j<mEdittexts.size(); j++){
                mEdittexts.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;

        }*/



        else if (id ==R.id.action_help)  {


            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Help");
            builder.setMessage("To use this app, first go to Create your Shopping List.\n" +
                    "Here, you can add items to your list. Once you have added all items, you can click the menu at the top right corner (or if it doesnt appear press your menu button beside your home button on your device, then click View your List.\n" +
                    "This will take you to the screen where you can view you shopping list with the items in aisle order to make your shop much easier.\n" +
                    "You can still add items at this point. Press the white background of each item to delete the item if you wish.");

            // add a button
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

            // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();





            return true;

        }




        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





    //use a relative layout and specify which ones are to layout_toRightOf and layout_below

    //DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN FAB IS PRESSED//
    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);




        //setup relative layout for the positioning of the objects
        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)), (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)));
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textview);


        checkbox.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);

        // RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textview));

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return checkbox;
    }



    private TextView makeTextview() {
        //create new textview
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);

        //setup layout

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textview.setTextSize(30);



        return textview;
    }


    private EditText makeEdittext() {
        //create new edittext
        EditText edittext = new EditText(this);

        //setup layout
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50); // Width , height
        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        edittext.setHint("qty");

        return edittext;

    }




    private View makeView() {
        //create new View

        View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        // LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setClickable(true);


        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        //setup layout

        return view;


    }






    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        //TODO I made this variable global, declared it at the very top of this file
        itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        // SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
        SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(this);


        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }



    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }}
```

the create.java intent part

```
  //takes the size of the list of spinners, for reference
            ArrayList<Integer> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
                spinnerList.add(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

            }
            Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
            newBundle.putIntegerArrayList("arraylist", spinnerList);
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(create.this, viewscreen.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("extraBundle", newBundle);
```

Comment: share the whole logcat report

Comment: get integerArrayList only when bundle is not null . so check for null value in each case

Comment: my post has exceeded word limit. here is the pastebin of my logcat @RahulChokshi https://pastebin.com/cpZgXfEt

Comment: it seems you getting `null` bundle object. check bundle null is not before you get element form bundle. and check your bundle `key`

Comment: spinnerArrayList  get null then it's possible so make sure that check with if condition.

Comment: how do I do that? how do I check

Comment: can u add setlist and pass intent code

Comment: how are u setting the bundle to the intent , did u use putExtra() with a string name?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use put arraylist value like

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arraylist", arraylist);
```

And get arraylist value use like below code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
```

Comment: i already have this in another activity. ```Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
            newBundle.putIntegerArrayList("arraylist", spinnerList);```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent gotIntent = getIntent();
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extraBundle");

please print bundle. because the bundle is null then an exception is created 

for example:-
send data:-

String[] _string=new String[2];
_string[0]="MONDAY";
_string[1]="TUESDAY";
Intent _intent = new Intent(this, second.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
_intent .putExtra("strings", myStrings);
_intent .putExtras(bundle);               
startActivity(_intent );


receive data:-

Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras=i.getExtras();

if(extras != null)  //this line is necessary for getting any value
{
    String[] _Values = i.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
    Toast.makeText(this, "value="+_Values [0]+""+_Values [1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check codes in main activity button click method, ensure put bundle and data correctly.
and in view activity, suggest writing like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extraBundle");
if (bundle!=null) {
    if(bundle.containsKey("arraylist") {
       ArrayList<Integer> spinnerArrayList = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");
       //do something
    }
} else {
     //log error info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for null value. Maybe the intent is null or the bundle you passed into it is null

```
Intent gotIntent = getIntent();
if ((gotIntent != null) && (gotIntent.getBundleExtra("extraBundle")  != null)) {
    Bundle bundle = gotIntent.getBundleExtra("extraBundle");
    if(bundle.containsKey("arraylist") {
       ArrayList<Integer> spinnerArrayList = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");
    }

}
```

Comment: I do that but stil get same error? What is it suppose to do

Comment: I have added another check, if you put these two null pointer check together, it must work. Please check the code change

Comment: Also, note the difference between "gotIntent" and "getIntent" ; the code is supposed to check the intents. The first 'if' statement checks whether there is a bundle in the intent, if there is a bundle, the second 'if' statement checks whether or not there is ArrayList in the bundle

Comment: it says method call expected for ```gotIntent().getBundleExtra```

Comment: You put gotIntent() instead of  gotIntent.

Comment: Please, check my code character for character,  and differentiate getIntent() from gotIntent and others, and tell me the exact error message. I have edited my code. Check it again

Comment: did you use putExtra(bundle,"extraBundle") while setting the bundle in the intent in the previous activity?

Comment: In correction to Kaveri: did you use putExtras("extraBundle" , bundle) when sending the intent? Or better still, show us the code for sending the intent

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the bundle as shown below:-

```
    Intent gotIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = gotIntent.getExtras();
    ArrayList<Integer> spinnerArrayList = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");
```

The method`getBundleExtra("String")` gets the bundle named String. While `getExtras()`   gets a bundle with all of the items placed into the array.Place your bundle with `putExtra(Bundle bundle, String tag)` , so that the `getBundleExtra(String tag)` will return that value.

To check for null ,

```
if(gotIntent != null && gotIntent.hasExtra("bundleExtras")){
      Bundle bundle = gotIntent.getExtras();
      ArrayList<Integer> spinnerArrayList = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have initialise your activity in your manifest

and use directly like this

> ```
>    ArrayList<Integer> list = getIntent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("")
> ```

Comment: Also change your class name view is default key word of java/android

Comment: oh ok. is that gonna affect anything

Comment: I changed my class name to viewscreen, but now am getting error on this line in my mainactivity screen (when the button is pressed)  ```startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, viewscreen.class));``` and this error https://pastebin.com/RiZsbV1a

Comment: you can check your arraylist should not be not when you send another activity

Comment: how do I initialise

Comment: like this
<activity android:name=".viewscreen"/>

Comment: do you have any suggestion